# jquery "unrecognized column IE8 not selecting

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

Building an extension ontop of a Business Intelligence software platform. Am building the following HTML

```
<ul class="project">
    <col1 id="col1">
        <li class="proj vis"></li>
        <li class="proj vis"></li>
        <li class="proj vis"></li>
    </col1>
    <col2 id="col2">
        <li class="proj vis"></li>
        <li class="proj vis"></li>
        <li class="proj vis"></li>
    </col2>
</ul>
```

Attempting to execute the following query.

```
 $('#col1 .proj.vis');
```

However it returns an empty set. On Chrome and other browsers it works perfectly.

Also tried the following

```
$('.project col').size()
```

The following will return elements, however it is not separated by col

```
$('.proj.vis');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever you are trying to do can't possibly work.

1. IE has known issues when using non-standard HTML elements.  I'm not sure if IE8, in standards mode, is affected or not.  IE8 is quirks mode certainly is.  More info available here: http://blog.whatwg.org/supporting-new-elements-in-ie
2. The call `$('#col1 .proj.vis');` returns the empty set in all browsers.  There is no element with the ID of `col1`.  `$('col1 .proj.vis');`, on the other hand, returns `3` under Chrome.

If you must use the element of `col1`, then in your document HEAD, before anything else happens, add the line:

```
// Make IE recognize this element.
document.createElement("col1");
```

(I tried creating a fiddle, but JS fiddle broke down when I switched to IE8 mode in the browser.)

Comment: Sorry, updated code. Forgot the Id. OH yeah an JSFIDDLe doesnt work on IE8, I dont know why people still use this browser..

Comment: The first part of my answer, however, still applies.  IE8 simply doesn't handle your non-standard element right... Updated my answer with a link.